Unable to send mail from Ubuntu - keyring library in R
My code (listed bellow) works in R Studio (Windows) but throws eror when I tried to execute it from command line on ubuntu.
My code:
library(keyring)
library(blastula)

keyring_unlock(password = "xx")

create_smtp_creds_key(
  
  id = "gmailKonkurencja2",
  user = "xx111@gmail.com",
  host = "smtp.gmail.com",
  port = 465,
  provider = "gmail" 
)


email2 <- compose_email(body = "Test")

email2%>%smtp_send(to = "xx@xx", from = "xx@gmail.com",
                    subject = "Test", credentials = creds_key("gmailKonkurencja2")  )

This code gives my eror as You can see bellow
The system key store has been updated with the "blastula-v1-gmailKonkurencja2" key with the `id` value "gmailKonkurencja2".
* Use the `view_credential_keys()` function to see all available keys
* You can use this key within `smtp_send()` with `credentials = creds_key("gmailKonkurencja2")`
Error in handle_setopt(h, ...) : Unknown option: login_options
Calls: %>% ... smtp_send -> <Anonymous> -> new_handle -> handle_setopt

I want to send this email everyday using crontab on ubuntu.

Maybe related: https://github.com/rstudio/blastula/issues/331. Maybe has to do with what cURL version you have installed on the system. In R on the ubuntu machine, try running curl::curl_version() to see what cURL version you are using.

My curl verion bellow. Is it source of problems?                               curl::curl_version()
$version
[1] "7.29.0"
$ssl_version
[1] "NSS/3.53.1"
$libz_version
[1] "1.2.7"
$libssh_version
[1] "libssh2/1.8.0"
$libidn_version
[1] "1.28"

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS.html Says that feature was added in 7.34 so it would appear that is the problem.

@MrFlick  Is it possible to install higher version of curl (than 7.29) ?
